# c# remove items when uncheck check box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, checkboxlist

When I check the checkbox in the checkboxlist, the checkbox.text will add into the listbox.
But when I uncheck the checkbox, the checkbox.text will be removed from the listbox.
But the problem is I do not know how to remove the selected items from the listbox.

[image: [Press here to see the picture][2]<br>]

For example, when i check the checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, the listbox will display
    checkbox1
    checkbox2
    checkbox3

However, when i uncheck the checkbox, Still Same 
I stuck at here. Help !!

here is my code:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked) listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox1.Text);

}

private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked) listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox2.Text);
}

private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox3.Checked) listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox3.Text);
}

private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox4.Checked) listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox4.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one funciton

```
 private void checkBoxCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
            if (cb != null)
                if (cb.Checked) listBox1.Items.Add(cb.Text); else listBox1.Items.Remove(cb.Text);
        }
```

And then add it for all your checkboxes as CheckedChanged event.

Comment: Thanks, you save my day. 
But I have a questions. If I have many checkbox, so is there any shortcut to do so instead of adding checkBoxCheckedChanged(sender, e); at each of the checkbox_CheckedChanged event?

Comment: select all of them and add that event

Answer (score 5):

```
if (checkBox3.Checked) 
    listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox3.Text);
else
    listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox3.Text);
```

Note that this will always remove whatever is in the `Text` property.  This means that, if I check the box, change the text in `textBoxX`, and then uncheck, it will remove a different item.

Answer (score 1):

The `Items` collection on a `ListBox` has a `Remove` method. Put an else in each of your `CheckedChanged` events and use the `Remove` method.

```
if (checkBox4.Checked) listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox4.Text);
else listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox4.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a common function and call. For e.g.

```
private void addRemove(CheckBox chk)
{
if (chk.Checked) 
    listBox1.Items.Add(chk.Text);
else
    listBox1.Items.Remove(chk.Text);
}
```

Call

```
addRemove(checkbox1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `Remove()` method. It accepts one argument that specifies the item to remove.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (checkBox1.Checked) 
        listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox1.Text);

    else
        listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox1.Text);

}

private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (checkBox2.Checked) 
        listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox2.Text);

    else
        listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox2.Text);

}

private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox3.Checked) 
        listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox3.Text);

    else
        listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox3.Text);

}

private void checkBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (checkBox4.Checked) 
      listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox4.Text);

   else
      listBox1.Items.Remove(checkBox4.Text);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If thats all you want to do why not assign the same event to every checkbox and do the below:-

```
CheckBox chkBox=(CheckBox)sender;
if (chkBox.Checked) 
    listBox1.Items.Add(chkBox.Text);
else
    listBox1.Items.Remove(chkBox.Text);
```

Comment: How to assign all the checkbox_CheckedChanged event into a single event so that i can easy to handle ?

Comment: look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/button there you have this event being assigned from properties window

Comment: I still cant get what you mean. Could you give me an example?